# Difference between laravel 5 and codeigniter 3

Tags: php, laravel, codeigniter, laravel-5

This may silly question. But I am going to start new project. I am quite confused which framework is best out of **Codegniter 3** and **Laravel 5**.
What is the main difference between them.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right now, I personally prefer Laravel since it supports PHP7 unlike CodeIgniter (I still haven't read if CodeIgniter 3 supports PHP7). And based on personal experience, Laravel (through Eloquent) has "beautifully-written-codes".

Here are some references for you to check out: (I made sure to post both sides to not be bias)

https://www.codeclouds.com/blog/laravel-vs-codeigniter-a-difficult-choice/

https://www.clickittech.com/developer/laravel-vs-codeigniter-which-one-is-the-best-to-use

http://www.codeigniterhands.com/codeigniter-or-laravel

http://laravel.io/forum/07-08-2014-laravel-vs-codeigniter-a-difficult-choice

https://therightsw.com/codeigniter-vs-laravel-vs-yii-vs-cakephp/ (with grades for usability)

Comment: Not to split hairs, but I am running codeigniter 3 on PHP 7 with no problems

Comment: @Brad, but a lot of resources say that CodeIgniter3 has problems with PHP7. :(

Comment: I have no idea what they would be. I have not seen a single hiccup

Comment: I am running codeigniter on PHP7 supported webserver, I think @Ronald want to say that you cant code it like PHP7. CodeIgniter 4 is now in development, very soon it will comes in production. But laravel is already a big framework and really nice.

Answer (score 1):

Each framework have their own features and capabilities, used during the development of application. Laravel is one of the highly used, open-source modern web application framework that designs customized web applications quickly and easily.Laravel is used not only for big project but also best to use for small project.
[Best framework in 2018](https://www.valuecoders.com/blog/technology-and-apps/laravel-best-php-framework-2017/)

If you want a framework with exceptional performance, with nearly no configuration, not using cmd and not interested with large scale libraries and also your project is in small scale it's better to use codeIgniter.

[CodeIgniter3 vs Laravel5](https://hashnode.com/post/codeigniter-3-vs-laravel-5-cj1xxrj5o003szt53hdpmp5cb)

Comment: I have a question - i got aware of laravel+voyager and it seems to be a good choice to have as pre-built boilerplate project so i can build my projects - with an existing admin panel. Question: is voyager a good fit to use for custom programming - like in codeigniter. What bothers me is the BREAD functionality - i don't think one has to implement all of your controller/models with these generators?! All in all - is laravel a good choice for converting my codeigniter project so that i have pre built admin area with access control and login etc. @denuka-nirmalee

Answer (score 0):

Both framework are good in there place.
Laravel made from multiple open source project which make laravel more efficient , reliable and secure.
Where, laravel used blade engine. 
It used composer for package manager.
It provide unit testing.
It provide more security.
It provide beautiful redis queue front portal called laravel horizon.
Disadvantage : laravel used **predis** which is slower, because it is written in php.where **phpredis** is more faster, but laravel 5.* Don't support it.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommend you to use Laravel beacuse of:

- Built in authentication
- Awesome migrations
- Artisan commands to do anything in your project
- Built in pagination (It's took long in Codeigniter)
- Eloquent (Very easy way to interact with your database)
- Relationships
- Routes
- Easy API building
- Easy debugging
- Huge number of packages and libraries etc.